# Print out if else statement with parameters?

Tags: javascript

I need to do this for a homework exercise, i need to print out if else statements with parameters in the function. This is what i already have but it doesnt print out anything.

```
function getSalaris(x, y) {

var salaris;

//If else
if (x == 'MBO' && y < 1) {
    salaris = '1800'
    document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML = 'Het salaris van de opleiding en ervaring is: &euro;' + salaris;
}

else if (x == 'MBO' && y <= 3) {
    salaris = '2000'
    document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML = 'Het salaris van de opleiding en ervaring is: &euro;' + salaris;
}

else if (x == 'MBO' && y > 3) {
    salaris = '2200'
    document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML = 'Het salaris van de opleiding en ervaring is: &euro;' + salaris;
}

else if (x == 'HBO' && y < 1) {
    salaris = '2000'
    document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML = 'Het salaris van de opleiding en ervaring is: &euro;' + salaris;
}

else if (x == 'HBO' && y <= 3) {
    salaris = '2250'
    document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML = 'Het salaris van de opleiding en ervaring is: &euro;' + salaris;
}

else if (x == 'HBO' && y > 3) {
    salaris = '2400'
    document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML = 'Het salaris van de opleiding en ervaring is: &euro;' + salaris;
}

}

getSalaris('MBO', 2);
```

Here is the HTML code, i really cant find the error in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <!--Link naar js-->
        <script src="Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <p id="resultaat"></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: pls show us the html part where you define `resultaat`

Comment: you will have to provide your html code to see whats failing there i guess.

Comment: What do you mean? You don't print out if else statements, you use them for changing the flow of your program.

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/agy65wg6/1/).

Comment: Put your script at the bottom of the body element.

Comment: where you call `getSalaris`?

Answer (score 4):

At the time the script is loaded, there is no element with id "resultaat". Load your script just before the closing body tag.